# OSERROR Exception not caught

Tags: python, operating-system, mkdir

Hi Here is some code in python.
As far as I know if there is some system level error mkdir should throw OSError exception
I do not understand why the OSerror exception is never caught.

```
if  not os.path.exists(dirpath):
        try:
            os.mkdir(dirpath)
            lg.log("Destination path created:"+dirpath)
        except OSError,e:
            if e.errno in [errno.EEXIST]:
                lg.logerror("Directory already exists.")
            else:
                lg.logerror("Some unknown error..")
                lg.logerror(e.strerror)
                raise
        except :
            lg.logerror("Some error in creating destination directory.")
```

Comment: You should print the full traceback, at least for debugging. Either add `raise` inside the `except`, or `print traceback.format_exc()`

Comment: Instead of `except:`, you can use `except Exception, e:
    print e` to print the actual error.

Comment: Also, though this is minor, put the `'Destination path created'` logging under an `else:` block at the end, lest it raise a different error

Comment: @mhlester good point made